# Can I be sure that reallocating less memory will always find enough of it?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, allocation

Let's say I have just `malloc`ed `x` bytes of memory, after doing something with them I want to `realloc` `y < x` bytes. Can I make that and yet be sure that my `realloc` will find enough memory? Example,

```
int *p = malloc(10);
if (p != NULL) {
    // Do something with `p`.
    int *p_ = realloc(p, 5);
    // Keep doing something else.
}
```

Should I make sure `p_` isn't `NULL` even though I have reallocated less memory than the original one? I think `*alloc` functions return `NULL` when the requested memory exceeds the available one, is the previous code safe to use?

Comment: Since `realloc` is documented to be able to fail you should of course always check the return value. Would it ever fail in your scenario? - probably not, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: "*Should I make sure p_ isn't NULL*". Yes you should. Why risk it? It's unlikely to fail but there is no guarantee that it won't.

Comment: You have to check for NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I be sure that reallocating less memory will always find enough of it?
> Can I make that and yet be sure that my realloc will find enough memory?

No, `realloc(p, 5);` may fail and return `NULL`.

---

> Should I make sure p_ isn't NULL even though I have reallocated less memory than the original one?

Yes, code, *when down-sizing* and return is `NULL`, could continue with the old value pointer - it is still valid.

```
int *p_ = realloc(p, 5); 
if (p_) {
  p = p_;
} else /* if new_size <= old_size and new_size > 0 */ {
  ; // Simply continue with the old `p`, it is still good.
}
// Do something with `p`.
…
free(p);
```

Note: this `else` path is, in general, hard to test.

---

> I think *alloc functions return NULL when the requested memory exceeds the available one, is the previous code safe to use?

Do not assume.  `realloc()` may return `NULL` if the new size is larger, the same or smaller than before.

---

Design consideration:

Returning `NULL` on `realloc()` when the size is reduced is plausible when 1) the number of memory *handles* is met (a system may only allow so many allocations) and `calloc()` could temporally need another one.  2) The new size is 0.  The details of return value on `*alloc(0)` have a history and are a bit contentious and not further discussed here.

In any case, as long as the new size is more than zero, a return of `NULL` implies some resource is at the end.  [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) suggest code proceed to the same error handling as when `calloc()` returns `NULL` due to a size growth.

Comment: Whose standard library do I need to file a bug against? If you can't downsize because you're out of arena handles, don't and say you did.

Comment: @Joshua "Whose standard library do I need to file a bug against?" --> There is no bug.  Returning `NULL` is allowed by the C spec.  To be clear about "code ... could continue with the old value pointer" is not a recommendation – simply a compilant option.  The later "proceed to the same error handling" is.

Comment: At this point it's a compatibility constraint. I've seen too much code that assumes that shrinking always works.

Comment: @Joshua This answer does not assume shrinking always works.  What about this answer do you find a compatibility constraint or a bug?

Comment: I find that most code that knows it's shrinking a buffer doesn't check and assumes realloc() succeeded. The idea of having separate handles for heap blocks including free heap block is unnatural.